# Is there a way to refresh window properties in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I have a bug in Android where users log in to my site through Facebook connect. When they click the button they are redirected to another tab to log in to Facebook. After logging in they are taken back to the page on my site.

The problem is when they are brought back to my site the page is cut in half for some reason. The height of the page is half that of what it should be. If I go to another tab manually and come back to that page on my site again it refreshes to normal height. By refresh I don't mean reload, just the height comes back to normal size.

I think this is a native android bug. I'm on Nexus 4 with Android version 4.2.2.

Anyway, a possible solution would be if I were able to fire some JavaScript which would "refresh" the window upon the user being redirected back to my site. Is there such a function in JavaScript (one that won't reload the page" but will refresh the windows width/height properties?

Comment: have you been able to try the jquery solution?

Answer (score 0):

you could try adding thes meta tags

```
<!-- axe browser caching MIGHT work -->
<meta name="expires" content="0">

<!-- just as bad as js below -->
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.yoursite.edu/">
```

js

```
// what you dont want
location.reload();

$(function() {
    $('html, body').css({'width':'100%', 'height':'100%'});
});
```